# DISTINCT e GROUP BY não funcionam no Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

tudo joia?

Recentemente peguei um trabalho pra fazer, e o solicitante estava precisando listar alguns dados em uma tabela. Eu iria fazer todas as perguntas referentes aqui, mas resolvi dividir em partes porque ficaria mais fácil a compreensão pra mim e pra outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.

Pra este caso, estou tendo problemas em realizar um SELECT com DISTINCT ou GROUP BY no MySQL com Codeigniter.

Estou tentando agrupar algumas datas para exibir um único registro, e não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

O resultado é este da imagem:

[image: Tabela com Datas]

Aqui abaixo deixo o código que utilizei.

Model

```
function get_datas() {

    $this->db->order_by($this->id, 'DESC');
    $this->db->group_by('data_registro');
    $this->db->from($this->tabela);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index() {

    $data = array(
        'show_clientes' => $this->mdl_clientes->get_datas(),
    );

    $flash_msg = $this->session->flashdata('flash_message');
    if (isset($flash_msg) && !empty($flash_msg)) {
        $data['flash'] = $flash_msg;
    }

    $this->load->view('graficos/vwGraficos.php', $data);

}
```

HTML:

```
            <?php if($show_clientes != FALSE) : ?>

                <?php foreach($show_clientes as $clnt) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?= $clnt->data_registro; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

Busquei vários exemplos na net, fiz as queries manualmente, digitando toda a sintaxe, mas o resultado é sempre o mesmo da imagem da tabela mais acima. Desde já, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Poderia informar a estrutura da tabela em que está realizando a consulta e qual é o objetivo final que quer alcançar? "Agrupar algumas datas para exibir um único registro", o que seria esse único registro?

Comment: É uma tabela de clientes, e existe o campo da data do registro de contato desse cliente. Como vários clientes são registrados todos os dias, o objetivo final é agrupar a quantidade de contatos durante cada dia. A princípio é isso. Mas no momento, o que eu preciso é que as datas não se repitam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente agrupar antes de ordenar, por exemplo:

**MODEL**

```
 $this->db->select();
 $this->db->group_by(); 
 $this->db->order_by(); 
 $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Apresentou o mesmo resultado. Não está agrupando.

Comment: Acabei de encontrar o erro. Em uma outra parte do código, o programador criou uma condição pra carregar uma outra função do model de clientes que estava anulando a função que criei para agrupar os registros. Utilizei a sua sintaxe pra organizar melhor o meu código e ficar mais legível. Obrigado pela ajuda.